# Generate 100 random numbers such that only 25 out of 100 numbers will be greater than 0.(remaining will be 0)

Tags: python, random

This is the code to print 100 random numbers in a 2-d grid.

```
[[random.randint(1,25) for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
```

How do I print the random numbers such that out of 100 randomly printed numbers, only 25 will be of value greater than 0 ? Remaining all 75 numbers should be 0, in random positions of the grid.

The is what I meant. For example lets consider, a 5 * 5 table where only 12 numbers are allowed to be greater than 0. Remaining all(13) numbers should be 0. The numbers should be  generated randomly and in random positions.

```
[[ 1, 0, 7, 0, 0],
 [5, 9 , 0 , 0 , 2]
 [3, 0 , 0 , 6, 0]
 [11, 7, 0 , 3, 0]
 [0, 0, 3,  9, 0]]
```

Comment: So these numbers are no longer random since you want a correlation between them

Comment: Exactly, @pythonic833. Since the zeroes aren't random, don't randomly generate them. Generate 25 non-zero random numbers, add 75 zeros, and `random.shuffle()` the result.

Comment: @pythonic833 That isn't really true, you can skew distributions to fit your fancy.

Comment: "Random" You Keep Using That Word, I Do Not Think It Means What You Think It Means

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sure, you can skew distributions but if exactly 75 out of 100 numbers should be zero you can't talk about randomly generating them anymore however skewed your pdf is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I might do it. I used the insight that only 25 of the numbers are actually randomly generated. The remaining 75 are fixed. This leads to the expression:

```
[random.randint(1,25) for i in range(25)] + [0]*75
```

You can mix in the zeroes randomly:

```
random.shuffle(result)
```

And reshape the result to be a 10x10 grid:

```
result = [result[i*10:(i+1)*10] for i in range(10)]
```

Complete program:

```
import random
import pprint

result = [random.randint(1,25) for i in range(25)] + [0]*75
random.shuffle(result)
result = [result[i*10:(i+1)*10] for i in range(10)]
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it without importing anything new or using shuffle:

```
import random

indexesOfZeros = []
for i in range(76):
    while True:
        num = random.randint(0,100)
        if num not in indexesOfZeros: 
            indexesOfZeros.append(num)
            break

vals = [random.randint(1,25) if i not in indexesOfZeros else 0 for i in range(100)]
grid = [vals[((x*10)-10):(x*10)] for x in range(1,11)]

print(grid)
```

Comment: This can be a lot simpler: `indexes_of_zeros = random.sample(range(0,100), 75)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

source_numbers = [0] * 75 + [random.randint(1, 25) for i in range(25)]
random.shuffle(source_numbers)
grid = []
for i in range(10):
    grid = grid + [source_numbers[i * 10 : (i + 1) * 10]]
```